# "WHILE" is broken after the first run through in Excel VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run an IF within a WHILE within a FOR. The FOR and the IF is working like it supposed to. But after the first successful run through the WHILE and it comes back from the FOR the WHILE only goes through once and does not look into the rest of the rows. Here is the code:

```
'COPY EACH PO TO ITS OWN SHEET ............................................

   'set the sequence variable
    For x = 1 To 50

    Dim LSearchRow, LCopyToRow As Integer

   'Start search in row 1
    LSearchRow = 2

   'Start copying data to row 2 in PO40 (row counter variable)
    LCopyToRow = 2

   'run the copy script for each PO
    While Len(Range("C" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

      'If value in column H = "sequence match", copy entire row to its particular sheet
       If Range("H" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = x Then

        'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
         Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
         Selection.Copy

        'Paste row into its particular sheet in next row
         sheets("PO" & x).Select
         Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         'Move counter to next row
         LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

      End If

      LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

      sheets(1).Select
      Application.CutCopyMode = False

   Wend

      sheets("PO" & x).Select
        Cells.Select
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

   Next x
```

[image]

Comment: Range(c2, c3...cn) are filled with data? Could you upload a picture? Your while bucle seems to work as expected...

Comment: A through G has data down to row 37 on the search sheet (Sheet 1)

Comment: I filled my sheet with some data in column C, and in a step-by-step debug works fine. Plz show us the excel sheet

Comment: This is just off-topic. Is better to use cells(i,j) instead of that range expresion which is a bit confusing. If tformat is not important, you dont need to .select and .copy to copy values from a cell to another

Answer (score 2):

I am not really following your "discussion" and certainly do not wish to intervene. Yet, I felt the urge to propose a few changes which might help with your problem:

```
Public Sub tmpSO()

Dim LSearchRow As Long, LCopyToRow As Long
Dim shtSource As Worksheet, shtTarget As Worksheet
Dim bolFound As Boolean

Set shtSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Name of the source sheet

'set the sequence variable
For x = 1 To 50
    'Verify the existence of a sheet before processing it...
    bolFound = False
    For Each shtTarget In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If shtTarget.Name = "PO" & x Then
            bolFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next shtTarget
    If bolFound = False Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't find target sheet PO" & x & Chr(10) & "Skipping... moving on to next sheet."
        GoTo NextSheet
    End If

    'Start search in row 1
    LSearchRow = 2

    'Start copying data to row 2 in PO40 (row counter variable)
    LCopyToRow = 2

    'run the copy script for each PO
    While Len(shtSource.Cells(LSearchRow, "C").Value) > 0

        'If value in column H = "sequence match", copy entire row to its particular sheet
        If shtSource.Cells(LSearchRow, "H").Value = x Then

            'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
            shtSource.Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Copy

            'Paste row into its particular sheet in next row
            shtTarget.Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Paste

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            'Move counter to next row
            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

        End If

        LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

    Wend

    shtTarget.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
NextSheet:

Next x

End Sub
```

Notes:

1. As suggested by @dpdragnev there is no more selecting in the above code.
2. Explicit coding means that you do not just use `ActiveSheet` or `Range` without stating which sheet you are referring to.
3. There were a few cumbersome uses of `Range("H" & CStr(LSearchRow))` which I changed to `Cells(LSearchRow, "H")`. I believe this to be more legible and I know `Cells` to be faster than `Range`.
4. The `Dim` was moved outside the x-loop. There is no need to `Dim` something 50 times.
5. When using `Dim` with multiple variables then you need to repeat the variable type **for each** variable. So, instead of `Dim LSearchRow, LCopyToRow As Integer` you need to write `Dim LSearchRow as Integer, LCopyToRow As Integer`.
6. I guess that `Integer` is just fine for now. But eventually (when dealing with Excel rows) you might be going beyond 32,000 (and something) rows. So, it is probably better to go with `Long`.
7. There is now a small "extra" at the beginning of the x-loop verifying the existence of a sheet before processing it (just for good measures).

Other than that. I couldn't find anything for now. Of course, there are more things which could be improved. Yet, I didn't want to change your code too much around. You two have put a lot of hard work into that.

<sub>The above code has **not** been tested. I merely wrote it from the top of my head and might include flaws which require some tweaking. In this case, feel free to ask me about it.</sub>

Comment: I did use it and it is not finding the data ... I see that you edited it. So I will recopy and see what happens. Thanks a lot for this. I see what you are doing and like it. EDIT - it says it cannot find target sheet which is your msg box based on false.

Comment: Well, then it's probably good that I implemented this check. Now you know what the problem is. There is a sheet missing you were trying to use in your past code without verifying first if that sheet actually exists. A common problem here might be that the sheet name is not `PO40` but `P040` (written with two zeros or two capital o) or `PO40 ` (with a leading or trailing space you cannot see). Check your sheet names where the message box pops-up.

Comment: I checked all O's and they are the letter and not the number. And the sheets do exist and this script is not finding them. I have gone back to my original script and now have it where the While does work until it does not find the value in Column H and then it breaks. This works without my FOR but when I wrap the FOR around it that is when it no longer ignores missing values. There will be missing values and I just want it to skip and move to the next one until it finds the others that do exist.

Comment: @James: we have already helped you resolve some bugs / errors and furthermore helped you improve / refine your code in so many ways. If you have a new question with new issues then please feel free to post a new question. Yet, I do not think that your current question still pertains to the original problem and should therefore be continued on this post.

Comment: I am VERY appreciative of your time and help. But your code did not work and you even said it might not: "The above code has not been tested. I merely wrote it from the top of my head and might include flaws which require some tweaking. In this case, feel free to ask me about it." So I am resorting back to my original code with dpdragnev suggestion which has gotten me closer. I just need to find why WHILE breaks with FOR wrapped around it. That is all. Thanks for you time and I may ask that as a new question per suggestion.

Comment: You are correct: I did write this and you may very well send me the file by email and I will have a look at it (when I have time). At the same time, I believe that posting your improved code as a new question is also a good idea as you will get more exposure and (potentially) more experts having a look at your code block.

Comment: Thanks, @Ralph! I appreciate it. I will be using your ideas and improvements to the code and will post accordingly. So trust me, I have learned something from your posting. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because originally you select Sheet(1) but later inside your While loop you are using sheets("PO" & x).Select?  The focus will switch to the new sheet and the data you are looking for in your while loop condition may not be there.

Without seeing your actual file this is just a guess.

Comment: Sheet(1) is where the rows are copied from and the ("PO" & x) is the sheet in the same workbook where they are pasted to starting at row 2. Then the WHILE needs to go back to Sheet(1) to search the next row.

Comment: Ok, didnt checked that

Comment: @dpdragnev, the move to right before Wend caused it to leave sheets blank instead of at least coping one row as before.

Comment: how do I add images so you can see the master?

Comment: image has been added to original post

Comment: It has been a while since I did a VBA project, but if I remember correctly, you could access a sheet without selecting it. For example: Sheets("PO" & x ).Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(2,1)).Value = some value

Comment: Wee need also H column

Comment: okay, I also moved "Application.CutCopyMode = False" to under "Sheets(1).Select" right above Wend and now I get the first three sheets updated but then no more after. I will edit my questions to reflect new changes and image

Comment: Did you try my suggestion to write directly to the target sheet without selecting it?  This might be the easiest and most reliable solution.

Comment: I am working on that now. Trying to find the best way to implement it based on a paste method since that is what this script is doing. I am not an expert so having to think my way through it slowly.

Comment: Whats the criteria for arranging these rows in PO sheets? perhaps i can find another solution

Comment: @csanjose, I just simple need to separate each PO from each other so I can run further scripts within their sheets and then save them as individual text files for a software program that only accepts text files.

Comment: One more thing. The numbers at the end created by Excel's ranking formula so I can have a consistent identifier because the POs are always changing and I cannot rely on them to run this particular script in my question. So I came up with using the Rank, and this script will create based on this ranking number. When I do this separately it works fine. But I am trying to reduce the size of the file and make it easy to increase the number if needed by using a loop.

Comment: PO is a Purchase Order number

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub pos()

For x = 1 To 50

    Dim LSearchRow, LCopyToRow As Integer

    LSearchRow = 2
    LCopyToRow = 2

    While Cells(LSearchRow, 3) <> ""

       If Cells(LSearchRow, 8) = x Then
        For j = 1 To 8
          Sheets("PO" & x).Cells(LCopyToRow, j) = Sheets(1).Cells(LSearchRow, j)
        Next
      End If

      LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
      LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
      
    Wend
     
   Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by altering @Ralph's code. I couldn't get the pasting down as written but adjusted it from old code and it works like a charm. Working Code is successful as follows ...

```
Dim LSearchRow As Long, LCopyToRow As Long
Dim shtSource As Worksheet

Set shtSource = sheets(1) 'source sheet

'set the sequence variable
For x = 1 To 50

    'Start search in row 1
    LSearchRow = 2

    'Start copying data to row 2 in PO40 (row counter variable)
    LCopyToRow = 2

    'run the copy script for each PO
    While Len(shtSource.Cells(LSearchRow, "C").Value) > 0

        'If value in column H = "sequence match", copy entire row to its particular sheet
        If shtSource.Cells(LSearchRow, "H").Value = x Then

            'Select row in first sheet to copy
            shtSource.Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Copy

            'Paste row into its particular sheet in next row
            sheets("PO" & x).Select
            Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            'Move counter to next row
            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

        End If

        LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

    Wend
        Cells.Select
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Next x
```

Thanks to @Ralph, @dpdragnev and @csanjose who posted here!